# Use value in colum as argument in function

Tags: r

I have two data frames, one with a list with 3 index variables: User, Log and Pass, and one of which has many values for each of these variables.

I'm trying to pass the many values from the big DF into a list within the smaller DF, so that I can perform summary statistics later.

```
Small.DF
User,Log,Pass,Valid.Event.Pass
1   11  76  Yes
1   11  46  Yes
1   15  38  Yes
1   15  47  Yes
1   15  386 Yes
1   15  388 Yes
1   8   119 Yes
1   8   120 Yes
1   8   121 Yes
1   8   122 Yes
1   8   123 Yes
1   16  35  Yes
1   16  37  Yes
1   17  22  Yes
1   17  102 Yes
1   12  203 Yes
1   12  205 Yes
1   12  207 Yes
1   12  209 Yes
1   12  24  Yes
2   13  29  Yes
2   1   31  Yes


Big.DF
     User,Log,Pass,Passing.Distance
    1   11  0   739.5
    1   11  0   411.5
    1   11  0   0
    1   11  0   739.5
    1   11  0   0
    1   11  0   739.5
    1   11  0   0
    1   0   0   739.5
    1   0   0   0
    1   0   0   739.5
    1   0   0   0
    1   0   0   739.5
    1   0   0   0
    1   0   0   739.5
    1   15  76  371.5
    1   15  76  371.5
    1   15  76  370.5
    1   15  767 368.5
    1   15  76  367.5
    1   15  76  366.5
    1   15  76  365.5
    1   15  76  364.5
    1   15  76  364.5
    1   15  76  363.5
    1   15  76  364.5
    1   15  76  0
    1   15  76  739.5
    1   15  76  369.5
    1   15  76  0
    1   15  76  739.5
    1   15  0   0
    1   15  0   739.5
    1   15  0   0
    1   15  0   739.5
    1   15  0   0
    1   15  0   739.5
    1   15  0   0
    1   15  0   739.5
    1   15  0   0
    1   15  0   739.5
    1   15  0   0
    1   15  0   739.5
    1   15  0   0
```

I'm interested in subsetting the values that match for these three variables in Big.DF but also the 100 values before and 100 values after.

To achieve this I've written a function that will create such a list:

```
newfn<- function(User,Log,Pass){
test<-subset(Sensor.Data[(min(which(Big.DF$User==User&Big.DF$Log==Log & Big.DF$Pass==Pass))-100):(max(which(Big.DF$User==User&Big.DF$Log==Log & Big.DF$Pass==Pass))+100),],select=Passing.Distance)
}
```

But I can't figure out how to apply this function over each row in smalldf.

The simplest explanation I can think of would be

```
Small.df$listofvalues<- newfn(Small.df$User,Small.df$Log,Small.df$Pass)
```

But that won't work for several reasons I can see....

If it were apply it would be something like this

```
Small.df$listofvalues<-apply(smalldf,1,newfn)
```

But this doesn't quite work....and sweep doesn't seem quite right either. Is there any function I'm missing?

Comment: I suggest using tidyverse and specifically the `nest` and `map` functions.

Comment: I've been fiddling around with this function....

Best I could come up with is 

SmallDF2 <-
  Small.DF %>%
  mutate(listoflists = map2(User, Log, Pass,newfn )) %>%
  print()

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out....

```
  rowfinder<- function(User,Log,Pass){
    subset(Sensor.Data[(min(which(Sensor.Data$User==User&Sensor.Data$Log==Log & Sensor.Data$Pass==Pass))-100):(max(which(Sensor.Data$User==User&Sensor.Data$Log==Log & Sensor.Data$Pass==Pass))+100),],select=LH.passing.distance)
  }
  SmallDF$LHvalues<-apply(SmallDF[,c('User','Log','Pass')], 1, function(y) rowfinder(y['User'],y['Log'],y['Pass']))
```